# PHP Class extension does not seem to work

Tags: php, class

And so, I had a class defined on config.php. BUt , I cannot get the class extend done in another file (calc.php).

So, this is the calc.php:

```
error_reporting(0);

    define('BASE_PATH','some_path');
    include_once(BASE_PATH.'\config\config.php');


class Calc extends Main
{

    var $conn;
    var $table;
    var $query;
    var $where;



     function connect_db($connect) 
    {   

        $connect = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD)
                       or die ("Got problem");
                   mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE)
                       or die ("Error: Can't access database");
         $this->connect = $conn;

    }



     function calc()    
    {



           if(isset($_POST['num_a']))
              $num_a = $_POST['num_a'];

            if(isset($_POST['num_b']))
              $num_b = $_POST['num_b'];

            if(isset($_POST['num_c']))
              $num_c = $_POST['num_c'];

            if(isset($_POST['num_d']))
              $num_d = $_POST['num_d'];

            if(isset($_POST['num_e']))
              $num_e = $_POST['num_e'];

            if(isset($_POST['num_f']))
              $num_f = $_POST['num_f'];

            if(isset($_POST['num_g']))
              $num_g = $_POST['num_g'];

            if(isset($_POST['num_h']))
              $num_h = $_POST['num_h'];

            if(isset($_POST['num_i']))
              $num_i = $_POST['num_i'];

            if(isset($_POST['num_j']))
              $num_j = $_POST['num_j'];

             $total_deduct = $num_b + $num_c + $num_d + $num_e + $num_f + $num_g + $num_h + $num_i + $num_j;
             $total_nett = $num_a - $total_deduct;

                if($num_a < $total_deduct)
                   $num_a * -1;

                      if($this->connect == 1)
                        {                         
                          $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_current_deductions
                                    (num_a,num_b,num_c,num_d,num_e,num_f,num_g,num_h,num_i,num_j)
                                    VALUES";

                            if($query)  
                            {  
                                if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 1 )  
                                {  
                                    return true;  
                                }  
                                else  
                                {  
                                    trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
                                    return false;  
                                }  
                            }           



                              echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3;url=http://localhost/some_path'>
                                          <table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td align ='center'>
                                                  <p style='font: 11pt Arial Rounded MT Bold; color:#999999;'>
                                                     Nett balance is ". $total_nett." <br/>
                                                     Total deduction is ". $total_deduct."
                                                  </p>
                                              </td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </table>";

                        }else{
                         exit;
                        }                       


    }  

  }
```

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: So, as you can see...after getting the results, the page will be redirected to some display page with Meta-Redirect, along with the results..but, nothing happened. Can anyone guide me to the solution? I had to stop my Satch Boogie guitar lesson because of this....

Comment: Are you aware that `error_reporting(0);` basically means: "If there are errors in my code please don't tell me about them"?

Comment: Off-topic, but you should replace `if (isset` lines with a foreach loop holding something that does a control on the data (like check it actually is a number)

Comment: Yes I'm aware about that..Those are only warnings of an undefined variable,even when I enable it..it's not showing the error that I need to know

Comment: you should set error_reporting to -1, it is easier to write when the light is on.

Comment: solve these warnings before doing anything else.

Comment: ok..will get back to you, greg0ire

Comment: Nothing shown...also, I need to tell you that, whenever i re-write the script in a non-object oriented format...the whole thing works...so, I'm guessing something wrong with the class....

Comment: Are you sure the config file is even being loaded? Also, what errors are you getting? If you can't tell us what errors you are receiving we really can't help you.

Comment: the config file is being loaded...i test it when I comment out the include file...I will get the error: Class 'Main' not found....and when I simply put 'Main2' instead of 'Main' in "class Calculate extends Main2"...I will get the same error, so I'm assuming, I'm able to get the Main class loaded...as for the errors, like I said..the only thing I get is an undefined function warning of a variable named $total_deduct, which I assigned inside the display page (I'm using Smarty)..so that , $total_deduct will be shown in the tpl file...

Comment: Where is Main defined? In config.php?

Comment: yes....basically, the Main class has the same written methods/functions as like Calc class...

Comment: Are you using any namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you did not instanciate any Calc object, nor that you called the `calc()` method on it.

Comment: You mean, the instantiation should take place in config.php ( main class ) or calc.php ?  Should be in the calc.php right?

Comment: In calc.php, since Calc is not available in config.php unless you include calc.php in it, which would create a circular reference... strange! The instantiation could take place at the very end of calc.php